# Writing ".shape" equivalent in Java

Tags: java, python, android, opencv

I am rewriting Python code into Java code (Android) and I don't know how to perform the function `.shape` on an image.

Python:

```python
def getProcessedImage(srcImage):
image = copy.copy(srcImage) 
print ("image.shape"), image.shape 

r = 600.0 / image.shape[1]   
dim = (600, int(image.shape[0] * r)) 
print ("dimension ="), dim
```

Java:

```java
public Mat getProcessedImage(srcImage) {
  Mat image = new Mat(srcImage);
  srcImage.copyTo(image);

  Object[] truple = new Object[Array.getLength(srcImage)] //Got stuck here and don't even think its correct 

  // Mat processedImage =.......
  return processedImage;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of srcImage?

Comment: srcImage is **Mat** @Uriel Frankel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in java to shape in python is `srcImage.size().width` and `srcImage.size().height`.